# How do I specify the Super key in dual-function-keys?

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux

I try to use dual-function-keys (part of interception tools) in order to use capslock as escape AND Super key.

My yaml file looks like this:

```
TIMING:
  TAP_MILLISEC: 150
MAPINGS:
  - KEY: KEY_CAPSLOCK
    TAP: KEY_ESC
    HOLD: KEY_SUPER
```

The tap functionality works fine, but holding capslock does not. I suspect the name of the super key is different, but don't know the correct name.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`evemu-record`** to find out the correct name. Run it and press the key.

In most cases it will be `KEY_LEFTMETA` for the left-hand <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, `KEY_RIGHTMETA` for the right-hand one, and `KEY_COMPOSE` for the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key.

`/usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h` (linux-headers) has a list of all valid codes.

You can also use evemu-record to compare what events are coming from the real keyboard, with the events that interception-tools generates as output.